# either..or distinction in Android <uses-feature> manifest

Tags: android, hardware, android-manifest

I'm developing an android app and need either the hardware feature `android.hardware.camera.flash` or `android.hardware.camera.front`. I want to assure that this app will be available for smartphones which have flashlight but no facing front camera. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way of expressly putting in an "either-or" constraint. You could add `android:required="false"` for both `<uses-feature>` elements, but then you will get devices that lack both features.

> I want to assure that this app will be available for smartphones which have flashlight but no facing front camera.

Have `android:required="true"` on the `android.hardware.camera.flash` feature and `android:required="false"` on the `android.hardware.camera.front` feature.